# DispatcherTimer.Start() starts the Tick in a background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) start a new thread?

I noticed that the code example below is non-blocking:

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

So in this code example, will `Tick` (i.e. `EventHandler`) be executed on a different thread or will it be executed on the same thread that is setting up the `dispatcherTimer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Tick` event handler is always raised in the thread that owns the `DispatcherTimer` object. The normal way to use that timer class is to create the object in the UI thread, and then the event handler will be raised in the UI thread.

But as far as your question about how this happens and whether `DispatcherTimer` starts a new thread goes…

The exact implementation of the timer is just that: an implementation detail. The framework could use a background thread for timing, or may use some other mechanism.

As it happens, the current implementation of `DispatcherTimer` uses the native `WM_TIMER` mechanism (i.e. no, it doesn't start a new thread). Which makes sense, as one feature of `DispatcherTimer` is to raise the timer event on the dispatcher thread, and a convenient way to do that is to have the timer notification come from Windows in that same thread, which `WM_TIMER` does.

But you can't and shouldn't *assume* this. All you really know is that `DispatcherTimer` promises to raise the timer event in the dispatcher thread.

Note that regardless, the `Start()` method would *necessarily* be non-blocking. If that method call blocked, it would negate every benefit of using a timer in the first place. :)

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but I also appreciate the important distinction between the two `DispatcherTimer` classes - I had always feared that I had hosed my UI because so many posts say `DispatcherTimer` is for the `UI Thread` which is true depending the case, but misleading at best.

I would like to clarify one thing regarding this answer (I know it is very old) - just because the `Start()` method is non-blocking, does this mean that it is also Asynchronous?  I would sincerely hope so since it's managed in it's own thread. . .

Comment: Actually - I may have answered this clarification on my own - testing this on a routine searching for a file's existence - if I use `Threading.ThreadStart` and a `BeginInvoke` command to run, I can continue the rest of the **initiating** subroutine (Dispatcher's originating thread for example), AND the application continues to run and perform other new subroutines, whereas using `DispatcherTimer` will block my application from moving forward with any other separate subroutines until the condition for the routine started by the `Dispatcher` is completed (meaning - file existence is confirmed).

Comment: @k1dfr0std: I see that the question had been modified since I posted my answer. The wording of my answer wasn't quite in line with the new version of the question, so I've edited it to fit it better. As far as your own comment's question goes, the `Start()` method isn't really _asynchronous_ per se, because by the time it returns, everything it was supposed to do has been done. One might consider the entire timer object asynchronous, since it effectively raises the timer event asynchronously, but the setup of the timer object itself is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting: there are two `DispatcherTimer` classes!

The first one is [`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx). This is the class in my question. As explained in the accepted answer, `Tick` will be executed on the same thread.

The second one is [`Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer). In the documentation of this class it says:

> The DispatcherTimer can be used to run code on the same thread that produces the UI thread. Code running on this thread has the privilege to create and modify objects that can only be created and modified on the UI thread.

So the `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer` will be setup on a UI thread and its `Tick` will also be executed on a UI thread!

Comment: Note that my answer applies regardless. Both versions of the `DispatcherTimer` class are specifically designed to raise the `Tick` event on the dispatcher thread. Whether they use a background thread for the actual timing is immaterial; that's an implementation detail you can't count on either way.

Comment: Note also that your question is hard to understand: it's not clear whether you are asking if calling the `Start()` method causes a new thread to be started, or if the `Tick` event itself is raised on a new thread. The two are completely different questions; I hope my answer has explained both, but if not, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho ! I've updated my question and accepted your answer.